# How can I prevent a child entity being removed from it's parent when I edit the child entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm making a program that models a recent local election in my area, and I have a Candidate Entity and a Party Entity with a OneToMany relationship (Party can have many Candidates and Candidates can have one party).

I'm using JpaRepository, Hibernate and Postman to test the endpoints, and all are working as I want them to, but for some reason, when I edit a Candidate that is in a party, the Candidate gets removed from the party, even if I explicitly state the Party of the Candidate in the editCandidate method.

Here are my Entity's and Controllers/Services:

```
package localelection.programming24hrstartagain.entities;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
@Table(name = "candidates")
public class Candidate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "candidate_id")
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "party_id", referencedColumnName = "party_id")
    private Party party;

    public Candidate(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public Candidate(String name, String surname, Party party) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.party = party;
    }
}
```

Candidate

```
package localelection.programming24hrstartagain.entities;


import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
@Table(name = "parties")
public class Party {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "party_id")
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private int votes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "party")
    private Set<Candidate> candidates = new HashSet<>();

    public void addCandidate(Candidate candidate) {
        candidates.add(candidate);
    }

    public void removeCandidate(Candidate candidate) {
        candidates.remove(candidate);
    }

    public Party(String name, int votes) {
        this.name = name;
        this.votes = votes;
    }
}
```

Party

```
package localelection.programming24hrstartagain.services;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import localelection.programming24hrstartagain.entities.Candidate;
import localelection.programming24hrstartagain.entities.Party;
import localelection.programming24hrstartagain.repositories.CandidateRepository;
import localelection.programming24hrstartagain.repositories.PartyRepository;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CandidateService {

    CandidateRepository candidateRepository;
    PartyRepository partyRepository;

    public CandidateService(CandidateRepository candidateRepository, PartyRepository partyRepository) {
        this.candidateRepository = candidateRepository;
        this.partyRepository = partyRepository;
    }

    public Iterable<Candidate> getAll() {
        return candidateRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Candidate findById(Long candidateId) {
        return candidateRepository.findById(candidateId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "No Candidate found for ID: " + candidateId));
    }

    public Iterable<Candidate> getCandidateByParty(Long partyId) {
        return candidateRepository.findCandidateByPartyId(partyId);
    }

    public void deleteCandidate(Long candidateId) {
        candidateRepository.deleteById(candidateId);
    }

    public Candidate save(Candidate candidate) {
        return candidateRepository.save(candidate);
    }

    public Candidate editCandidate(Candidate candidate) {
        //candidate.setId(candidate.getId());
        candidate.setName(candidate.getName());
        candidate.setSurname(candidate.getSurname());
        candidate.setParty(candidate.getParty());
        return candidateRepository.save(candidate);
    }


}
```

CandidateService

```
package localelection.programming24hrstartagain.services;

import localelection.programming24hrstartagain.entities.Party;
import localelection.programming24hrstartagain.repositories.CandidateRepository;
import localelection.programming24hrstartagain.repositories.PartyRepository;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class PartyService {

    PartyRepository partyRepository;
    CandidateRepository candidateRepository;

    public PartyService(PartyRepository partyRepository, CandidateRepository candidateRepository) {
        this.partyRepository = partyRepository;
        this.candidateRepository = candidateRepository;
    }

    public Iterable<Party> getAll() {
        return partyRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Party findById(Long partyId) {
        return partyRepository.findById(partyId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "No Candidate found for ID: " + partyId));
    }

    public Party save(Party party) {
        return partyRepository.save(party);
    }

}
```

PartyService

```
package localelection.programming24hrstartagain.controllers;


import localelection.programming24hrstartagain.entities.Candidate;
import localelection.programming24hrstartagain.entities.Party;
import localelection.programming24hrstartagain.services.CandidateService;
import localelection.programming24hrstartagain.services.PartyService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/candidates")
public class CandidateController {

    @Autowired
    CandidateService candidateService;

    @Autowired
    PartyService partyService;

    // Create candidate

    // WORKING
    @PostMapping("/new")
    public Candidate addCandidate(@RequestBody Candidate candidate) {
        return candidateService.save(candidate);
    }

    // Add candidate to a given party

    // WORKING
    @PutMapping("/add/{candidateId}/{partyId}")
    public Party addCandidateToParty(@PathVariable Long candidateId, @PathVariable Long partyId) {
        Candidate candidate = candidateService.findById(candidateId);
        Party party = partyService.findById(partyId);

        candidate.setParty(party);
        candidateService.save(candidate);

        return party;
    }

//    // Edit candidates for a given party
//
//    // Not working as intended. Currently edits candidates, but removes them from their party.
//    @PutMapping("/edit/{candidateId}")
//    public Candidate editCandidate(@PathVariable Long candidateId, @RequestBody Candidate candidate) {
//        candidate = candidateService.findById(candidateId);
//        Party party = candidate.getParty();
//        return candidateService.editCandidate(candidate);
//    }

    // Edit candidates for a given party

    // Not working as intended. Currently edits candidates, but removes them from their party.
    @PutMapping("/edit/{candidateId}")
    public Candidate editCandidate(@PathVariable Long candidateId, @RequestBody Candidate candidate) {
        candidate.setId(candidateId);
        return candidateService.editCandidate(candidate);
    }

    // Remove candidate from a party without deleting them

    // Working
    @Transactional
    @PutMapping("/remove/{candidateId}/{partyId}")
    public Party removeCandidate(@PathVariable Long partyId, @PathVariable Long candidateId) {
        Party party = partyService.findById(partyId);
        Candidate candidate = candidateService.findById(candidateId);

        party.removeCandidate(candidate);
        candidate.setParty(null);
        partyService.save(party);
        candidateService.save(candidate);
        return partyService.findById(partyId);
    }


    // Delete candidates for a given party

    // WORKING AS INTENDED
    // Will delete a candidate if Party == null. If it != null, it will remove candidate from party
    // and then it will delete the candidate. Prevents deletion of party when deleting candidate
    // which was a problem I was facing.
    @Transactional
    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{candidateId}")
    public void deleteCandidate(@PathVariable Long candidateId) {
        if (candidateService.findById(candidateId).getParty()!= null){
            removeCandidate(candidateService.findById(candidateId).getParty().getId(), candidateId);
        }
        candidateService.deleteCandidate(candidateId);
    }

    // Get all Candidates

    // Working
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public Iterable<Candidate> getAllCandidates(){
        return candidateService.getAll();
    }

    // Get all candidates for a given party

    // Working
    @GetMapping("/parties/{partyId}")
    public Iterable<Candidate> getCandidatesForParty(@PathVariable Long partyId){
        return candidateService.getCandidateByParty(partyId);
    }

}
```

CandidateController

```
package localelection.programming24hrstartagain.controllers;


import localelection.programming24hrstartagain.entities.Party;
import localelection.programming24hrstartagain.services.CandidateService;
import localelection.programming24hrstartagain.services.PartyService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/parties")
public class PartyController {

    @Autowired
    CandidateService candidateService;

    @Autowired
    PartyService partyService;

    // Working
    @PostMapping("/new")
    public Party addParty(@RequestBody Party party) {
        return partyService.save(party);
    }


    // Working
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public Iterable<Party> getAllParties(){
        return partyService.getAll();
    }

    // Working
    @GetMapping("/{partyId}")
    public Party getPartyById(@PathVariable Long partyId) {
        return partyService.findById(partyId);
    }


}
```

PartyController

The endpoint in question is in the CandidateController. It works fine when the Candidate doesn't have a party, but when the Candidate is inside a Party, it edits them, but removes them from their Party.

Is there a way to stop this from happening? I've tried explicitly stating the Party, as can be seen in the CandidateService Class' editCandidate method, but it doesn't work.

I've also tried explicitly stating the Candidates Party in the CandidateController, but again, it doesn't work as intended.

I've been looking all over for a solution, but all I can find is stuff on deleting a Child Entity when it's Parent is deleted and threads surrounding deletion.

I would really appreciate someone pointing out where I'm going wrong.

For clarification: There is no Error being thrown. It works without complaint, just doesn't give me the intended result.

https://gyazo.com/ccd3fd11d5a5983cb6671fd6dfa47553 - Party entity in DB

https://gyazo.com/df7028e390e613a27fb4bd01724804c4 - Candidate entity in DB

Comment: Hi! When you pass a Candidate object inside the CandidateController, do you set any party to it?
In other case you will override your "party" value with null that comes from controller, which removes your Candidate from already existing Party.

Comment: Inside the method, it fetches the candidates from the candidateService, using the candidateId that's passed as a PathVariable and then sets all the values to the values passed in the RequestBody candidate. Are you saying that I need to add the party_id or something like that to the RequestBody so that it will keep the Candidate in the party?

Comment: Sorry, missed a part when you retrieve an entity by id in controller. Look a bit counterintuitive for me. I thought that you might just pass empty object from RequestBody to service and save it.

Comment: Still, as far as I know, there are only 1 way to exclude candidate from party - set "party" field as null. Could you please check your service .save() method inside your .edit() method? Is party object exists there for the candidate you're trying to edit?

Comment: The save method is just
public Candidate save(Candidate candidate) {return candidateRepository.save(candidate); }
So as far as I'm seeing, it should be just saving the whole candidate object, and not changing any fields itself

Comment: I mean "candidateService.editCandidate()" method. Last row in this method is "return candidateRepository.save(candidate)". Could you please check your candidate object there? Does it have "party" field as not null value?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that unfortunately :/ Currently it's got candidate.setParty(candidate.getParty); but that doesn't seem to be applying because the party for the candidate I'm editing isn't null, but it's still being set to null after calling the method.

Comment: Well, you can just debug you code, set a breakpoint on necessary line and check your object values.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/ad9958eae5e4a27d6cc44db80adc6671 Not sure If set the breakpoint right because I've never done it before, but I set it on the line where I call candidateService.editCandidate(candidate) in the CandidateController and it's showing the party as null here.

Comment: Could it be because my database is only referencing the party_id and so the Party in the Candidate is null? I just tried fetching the Candidate using the candidateService.findById(candidateId) method and even though it's getting a candidate that is part of a party, the Party is still null.

Comment: Yes, it should be because "party" field inside Candidate object is null. So, during save operation (inside your "edit" method) you also pass a reference to party as null and because of that you remove your candidate from a aprty.

Comment: Is there a way to fix that without just adding the candidate back to the party after he's been edited? The only way I can think of right now is by making a method that first calls removeCandidate, then editCandidate, then addCandidateToParty, but that seems way more drawn out than I feel it should be.

Comment: @Sintry have you managed to solve your problem?

Comment: @Johannnes unfortunately not. I got around it by having 2 separate methods, one that would take just a candidateId as a PathVariable and one that took a candidateId and PartyId that effectively just added the candidate back to the party after they were edited.

Comment: I assume your application returns a JSON to Postman: When it does, the @JsonBackReference on the "party" field in the Candidate.class makes it return "null" for the Candidate's "party" within the JSON. And if you edit the Candidate in Postman and send it back to your application "party" is still "null". Does that make sense for you? Please check what's in the JSON that your application returns to Postman when you simply get one specific Candidate whom you know to be in a party.